# How can i write a simple rewrite rule in htacess for a file in the sites root directory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Ive been trying to get my sites htacess to provide effective rewrites for my filepages but im doing something  wrong.  My directory structure is very simple. All my files are in the root folder. So far my htacess looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-page.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example-page.com
    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   /front    /front_page.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   /redirect    /redirect-page.php
```

This is working when im calling the page like "www.example-page.com/front_page.php (as it would anyway since the file is in the root folder). However the rewrite rules are not working and [www.example-page.com/front](http://www.example-page.com/front) (and all the rest) are giving me 404 errors. I know this format can work or something very similar to it as ive used it before on other sites. Im quite confused.  Does somebody know  what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have multiple domains/hostnames on this account?

Answer (score 0):

Write the directives like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^front$ /front_page.php [L]

RewriteRule ^redirect$ /redirect-page.php [L]
```

There doesn't seem to be a need for all your additional *conditions*? I assume you only have the one domain `example-page.com` and you don't have a file called `/front` etc.

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. You should also include start/end-of-string anchors on the regex so that you only match `front` exactly and not match it *anywhere* in the URL-path.